# each(): array pointer doesn't work properly

Tags: php

Please consider this code

```
var_export ($dates);
while (list($key, $date) = each($dates))
{
    echo("current = ".current($dates));
    echo("key = " . key($dates));
}
```

result is

```
Array
(
    [1359928800] => 1359928800
)

current =
key =
```

I expected it should return `1359928800`, where I am wrong?

Comment: You probably haven't reset the array pointer from a previous operation. Why not just use a `foreach` loop instead?

Comment: @impl That is the most probable explanation. Maybe you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

When working with arrays there is a different less archaic construct for handling iterations: foreach ([documentation here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)).

I'd recommend iterating over the array in this manner. It's much easier to read and nearly impossible to get wrong. In addition, you don't have to worry about the possibility of ending up in an infinite loop as mentioned in the Caution [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php).

```
<?php
var_export($dates);
foreach($dates as $key => $value) {
    echo("current = ".$value);
    echo("key = ".$key);
}
```

Comment: actually I need use prev, reset, next, it seems foreach doesn't work with it

Comment: foreach automatically resets the array's pointer to the beginning of the array. aka, reset() is automatically called right before iteration. if this isn't working for you, what is the error being thrown? if you are indeed working with an array, then this should work.. foreach was implemented in PHP 4, what version of PHP are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

Why not make use of `$key` and `$date`?

```
while (list($key, $date) = each($dates))
{
    echo("current = ".$date); // 1359928800
    echo("key = " . $key); // 1359928800
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **reason** is that `each` already advances the pointer.

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) states:

> Return the current key and value pair from an array and advance the array cursor.

So inside the loop `current` refers to the *next* element. In your case there is no next element, so it's `false`. You should use `$key` and `$date` or better, use `foreach`, like already suggested.